# Financial History Review Bibliography Style

Tags: bibliographystyle

First time writing a question, just started learning Latex a few months ago. I am writing an article aimed to be published at the Financial History Review (Cambridge) and they use a Bibliography style I cant find. I usually use  natbib {apalike} for most papers. Here is an example of the Style they require[image] and the link to the author guidelines is here https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/financial-history-review/information/instructions-contributors.

If anyone can give me a hand, I appreciate it.

Comment: They will reformat your paper, won't they? Or you just submit the final pdf to them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. When confronted with the task of replicating an uncommon bibliography style, it's often a good idea to employ the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package. The utility provides a menu-driven, interactive interface; each question comes with multiple choice answers, one of which being the default. The good news is that the `makebst` was created by the author of the `natbib` package and that its code works very well with the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: I noticed that their instructions also state: "Please note that you should supply a WORD or RTF document for the main text body (including footnotes, bibliographical references, appendices) and a different single document in PDF for Tables and Figures." You may therefore want to verify with the editorial office that they'll accept a LaTeX document

Comment: thanks for the help, yes I also noticed the WORD requirement, what I generally do in those cases is work on LaTex and do a pdf-doc convert, and reformat.